# corona movieclip is not appearing on device

Tags: android, coronasdk

i've got a movieclip that is working very well on the simulator, appearing during the load
and when played

```
mc1 = movieclip.newAnim{ "assets/mc1.png", "assets/mc2.png", "assets/mc3.png"}
mc1.x = 400
mc1.y = 200


mc1:play() -- play all frames
mc1:reverse{ startFrame=3, endFrame=1, loop=3 }
```

but it doesnt appear at all on my samsung S2 running 4.1.2
the 3 png files are 16kb each so memory shouldnt be a problem

the rest of the screen works fine.
anyone out there having the same problem ?

thanks
claude

Answer (score 0):

If its working in simulator then it should work on the device. The only reason it might not work would be the case sensitivity of the media files. Check that the file name written in your code matches exactly with the file name of the media file.
I had a similar problem and then realized that my file extension was .PNG while i wrote .png in the code.

If this is not the problem then you should connect your device in debug mode and get the console output from ADB maybe the device is trowing some runtime errors.

Comment: no, .png it is in the correct case.. 
i've been trying for 2 hours last night to get ADB to work (never used it before) .. will try again tonight ..

Comment: here is the answer from the log:
'I/Corona  (32248): Runtime error'
'I/Corona  (32248): C:\claude\AAACorona\aupo-mlv\movieclip.lua:69: ERROR:'
' table expected. If this is a function call, you might have used '.' instead of ':''
'I/Corona  (32248): stack traceback:'
'I/Corona  (32248):      [C]: ?'
'I/Corona  (32248):      [C]: in function 'insert''
'I/Corona  (32248):      C:\claude\AAACorona\aupo-mlv\movieclip.lua:69: in function 'newAnim''

Comment: sorry @HunterSeeker , i cant format this comment properly ..
can you read it ?